# Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined. videojs async loading

Tags: javascript

1. So i have a js file as follows:-

```js
(function(){
    console.log("Starting Point");

    // Creating and Appending scripts dynamically

    function createScript(src) {
      console.log("script for js"); 
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = src;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
    
    // End script tags Here

    function createLink(href) {
      console.log("script for links"); 
      var link = document.createElement('link');  
      link.href = href;
      link.rel = "stylesheet";
      link.type = "type/css";
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }     

    // DIV 1
    // Create a main Div to hold everything

    createScript('http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.7.1/video.js');
    createScript('lib/videojs-contrib-ads/videojs.ads.js');
    createScript('lib/vast-client.js');
    createScript('videojs.vast.js');

    createLink('http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.7.1/video-js.css');
    createLink('lib/videojs-contrib-ads/videojs.ads.css');
    createLink('videojs.vast.css');

  
    console.log("Create mainDiv");
    var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
    mainDiv.id  = 'ad_placement';
    // mainDiv.style.float = "right";
    var currentScript = document.currentScript;
    currentScript.parentElement.insertBefore(mainDiv, currentScript);
    // document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
    console.log("End MainDiv"); 

    // End main Div here


    // DIV 2 
    // Div to hold the video
    
    console.log("Create innerDiv")
    var divContainer = document.createElement('div');
    divContainer.class = 'example-video-container';
    divContainer.style.display = 'inline-block';
    mainDiv.appendChild(divContainer);   
    console.log("Create innerDiv")

    // End parent Div here (parent of video div/tag)

    // Video Player Below 
    // Create the video tag for html video player
    console.log("Video Creation Started");

    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.id = 'vid2';
    video.width = 300;
    video.height = 250;
    video.class = 'video-js vjs-default-skin';
    
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.controls = true;
    video.muted = true;
    video.preload = 'auto';
    video.poster = "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg";
    //video.data-setup = '{}'; 
    
    // Function to create sources for video
    function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {
      var source = document.createElement('source');

      source.src = src;
      source.type = type;

      element.appendChild(source);
    }

    addSourceToVideo(video, 'http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4', 'video/mp4');
    addSourceToVideo(video, 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4', 'video/webm');
    addSourceToVideo(video, 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4', 'video/ogg');

    console.log("Video Creation End");
  
    console.log("Para Started");

    var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    paragraph.innerHTML = "Video PlayBack Not Supported";
    video.appendChild(paragraph);

    video.load();
    //video.play();
    divContainer.appendChild(video);

    console.log("Para end");
    // Video player creation ends here
    
    console.log("Before calling videojs");
    var vid2 = videojs('vid2');
    console.log("After calling videojs");
    vid2.muted(true);
    
    vid2.ads({
      timeout: 5000
    });
    
    vid2.vast({
      url: 'vast_tag_url'
    });

    vid2.on('readyforpreroll', function() {
      vid2.ads.startLinearAdMode(); 
      vid2.one('ended', function() {
        vid2.ads.endLinearAdMode();
        console.log("ad finished");
        document.getElementById('adPlacement').innerHTML="<img src='https://wallazee.global.ssl.fastly.net/images/variant/20140109-11d5e6789afea899c324f5d4cbfa00eca24c58c8b790e1d6305c36e-1024.png' width=300 height=250 border=0/>";
      });

    });

    vid2.on('adtimeout', function() {
        console.log("timout happened")
        document.getElementById('adPlacement').innerHTML="<img src='https://wallazee.global.ssl.fastly.net/images/variant/20140109-11d5e6789afea899c324f5d4cbfa00eca24c58c8b790e1d6305c36e-1024.png' width=300 height=250 border=0/>";
    });

    console.log("End of file");

})();
```

1. So i am getting video.js not defined error when i include this file in html page. Need a javascript solution. (I can't use jquery)
2. Where am i wrong.it works on normal html page when we have css and js in head then a div with video and js functions in body.

   3. when i created a js and imported then its a problem

Comment: You set the class for the video incorrectly, change it to `video.className = "video-js vjs-default-skin";`

Comment: @TheMintyMate :- I tried this but error exists :-(

Comment: you need to do this anywhere else you attempt to give an element a class (which you have). When setting a class for an element, you use the following syntax: `element.className = "a_class_name";` @MiHawk

Comment: @TheMintyMate:- Done. Problem is still there.